# "No module named keras" error in transformers

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to load a pretrained BERT model in a sagemaker training job using the transformers library and I'm getting "No modul named keras error". You can find the relevant code, imports and requirements.txt below

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from tensorflow.keras import applications
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import losses
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras import metrics
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from transformers import TFAutoModel
from transformers import BertTokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU

bert1 = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained('path/to/BERT', from_pt=True)
```

requirements.txt (I haven't set any versions for these):

```
transformers
torch
SentencePiece
```

Other env settings:

```
Python= 3.7
tensorflow= 2.3
```

I had used these exact settings a few months back and faced no issues, so not sure why I'm getting this error now

Edit: based on the answers I received, I added Keras to my requirements and also added from TensorFlow import keras statement, and now I'm getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.saving'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out a new version of the huggingface-transformers library was released a few days ago. So setting the transformers version to 4.20.1 solved the issue.
Maybe upgrading TensorFlow to 2.7 might work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following command, maybe keras is not preinstalled in the workspace

```
!pip install keras
```

Comment: Added keras to my requirements and now I'm getting this error now: ImportError: cannot import name 'get_config' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.context'

Answer (score 0):

Your TensorFlow module may be installed in a different env. Try to add conda environment as the python interpreter and install all your libraries to it. it will work properly.

Comment: I'm using a sagemaker training job, so the env and container come with tensorflow already pre-installed

Answer (score 0):

I had keras-nightly installed, removing it fixed it.